# How to add a custom attribute to a category using the API?

Tags: attributes, magento-2.1, api, rest-api, category-attribute

Is there a way to add a custom attribute to a category?

I only see these options in the [swagger documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#resource_catalogCategoryAttributeRepositoryV1):

- GET    `/V1/categories/attributes/:attributeCode`
- GET    `/V1/categories/attributes`
- GET    `/V1/categories/attributes/:attributeCode/options`

I don't see any way to create an attribute or attribute group for the category.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
$installer = $setup;

$installer->startSetup();

$categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

$entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);

$attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);

$categorySetup->removeAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'my_attribute' );

$categorySetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, 'my_attribute', [
             'type' => 'int',
             'label' => 'My Atrribute ',
             'input' => 'select',
             'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
             'required' => false,
             'sort_order' => 100,
             'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
             'group' => 'General Information',
        ]
    );

$installer->endSetup();
```

For More information, Please [follow this link](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-add-custom-eav-attribute-to-category-or-customer)

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom module and add below code to **InstallData.php**

at `app\code\Vendor\ModuleName\Setup\InstallData.php`

```
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;\
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {

        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
                    'category_marketplace',
                    [
                        'type' => 'int',
                        'label' => 'Test',
                        'input' => 'select',
                        'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                        'required' => false,
                        'visible' => true,
                        'user_defined' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 100,
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'group' => 'General Information',
                    ]
                );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below code inside app/code/Vendor/Categoryattr/Setup/InstallData.php file,

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\CategoryAttribute\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory; 
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
         */ 
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'custom_attribute',
                      [
                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'label' => 'Custom Attribute Description',
                        'input' => 'textarea',
                        'required' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 100,
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                        'group' => 'General Information',
                        'is_used_in_grid' => true,
                        'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                        'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
            ]
        );


    }
}
```

remove var folder and run command php bin/magento setup:upgrade to working inside category.